# How do i logout the user logged in using socialte if he logs in from another browser?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I have implemented socialite login using Google and LinkedIn. My requirements are that I need to have the user only be able to login from one device at a time, so in case the user logs in using another device the first logged in device will be logged out.

I have two types of users, ones that login using a normal sign up process and the ones that use Socialite login. If a user has used the same email on a normal sign up and he wants to login using google or linked-in his account will be the same.

I have two tables one for admins and one for users as well, and two different models.

If my user signs in using his username and password I managed to make it work using the following code:

In session.php

```
    'expire_on_close' => true,
```

In CustomDatabaseSessionHandler.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Extensions;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException;
use Illuminate\Session\DatabaseSessionHandler;

class CustomDatabaseSessionHandler extends DatabaseSessionHandler
{

    /**
     * Add the user information to the session payload.
     *
     * @param array $payload
     * @return $this
     * @throws BindingResolutionException
     */
    protected function addUserInformation(&$payload): static
    {
        if ($this->container->bound(Guard::class)) {
            info(($this->user() ? get_class($this->user()) : null));
            $payload['userable_type'] = $this->user() ? get_class($this->user()) : null;
            $payload['userable_id'] = $this->userId();
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the currently authenticated user's ID.
     *
     * @return mixed
     * @throws BindingResolutionException
     */
    protected function user(): mixed
    {
        return $this->container->make(Guard::class)->user();
    }
}
```

In AppServiceProvider

```
        Session::extend('custom-database', function ($app) {
            $table = $app['config']['session.table'];
            $lifetime = $app['config']['session.lifetime'];
            $connection = $app['db']->connection($app['config']['session.connection']);

            return new CustomDatabaseSessionHandler($connection, $table, $lifetime, $app);
        });
```

Changed the SESSION_DRIVER in .env to 'custom-database'

Created a LoginListener with the following code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class LoginListener
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     */
    public function handle(object $event): void
    {
        $user = $event->user;
        DB::table('sessions')->where('userable_id', $user->id)->where('userable_type', get_class($user))->delete();
    }
}
```

I have added the following to services.php

```
    'google' => [
        'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('APP_URL') . '/oauth/google/callback',
    ],
    'linkedin-openid' => [
        'client_id' => env('LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('APP_URL') . '/oauth/linkedin_openid/callback',
    ],
```

My problem is whenever i close the browser it's not logging out, and whenever i am logging in using another device it's not logging out, this problem is happening only when using the socialite login.

Comment: `My requirements are that I need to have the user only be able to login from one device at a time`...why, exactly? That's super unfriendly to users. Hardly any systems do things like that, it's only usually if they have very strict security requirements due to the nature of the site contents or something. But if you're letting people log in with Google or LinkedIn etc I can't imagine it's all that critical. Obviously it's up to you, but this kind of feature is a great way to really annoy your users, so don't do it unless there's an absolutely compelling reason to.

Comment: since linkedin and google sessions are persistant through multiple browser session, how do you think it would be implemented ? you can't force logout a user from linkedin on the old browser if you detect a new browser. Even if you manage to lock the session on your website, it will be a fight of who refresh the page last. dont see how to implement this.

Comment: @ADyson this is a financial system, we have to have the user logged in in ony one session for security reasons. I know it's user unfriendly but yep!

Comment: @N69S, well the sessions on my app are tied to the database, I thought maybe there might be a way to do that using my database!

Comment: @alcolopa If that's the case then I'd suggest that maybe using federated logins from 3rd party providers isn't the way to go. P.S. I've worked on or with multiple "financial systems" (it depends exactly what you mean by that I guess) over the years, and none had this requirement. Also, none of them let you use your google account to authenticate, either.

Comment: You're right, i see my bank app has no google and linkedin login! @ADyson. So technically there is no way to do that

Comment: I didn't say it was technically impossible (although I'd guess it's likely to be very difficult and/or unreliable to enforce the one-device rule), I'm just suggesting it's not a good idea